# VBA regex repeating group only gets first occurence

Tags: regex, vba, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have the following sub-string

```
var fixedDays =['20180101:V','20180102:V','20180106:W','20180107:W','20180113:W','20180114:W','20180120:W','20180121:W','20180124:V','20180127:W','20180128:W','20180203:W'
```

which is part of a bigger string(big_string) on which I am performing the regex.
I am trying to get all the numbers from this sub-string : 20180101 , 20180102 ...

Here is my code:

```
sREG.Global = True
sREG.MultiLine = True
sREG.IgnoreCase = True    
sREG.Pattern = "var fixedDays =\[(?:'(\d{8}):[V|W]',?)+\];"
Set sRES = sREG.Execute(big_string)
```

But it returns only the last number 20180203.

I know it has to do with greedy/lazy quantifiers , but cannot manage to do it.

Comment: You may either 1) remove `var fixedDays =\[(?:` and `)+\];` from the pattern, or 2) get the whole string with first regex, then get submatches with second regex.

Comment: I thought about getting the whole string before getting the numbers, but I somehow hoped there is a onehsot solution. thanks anyway;

Answer (score 0):

a VBA solution, though not a Regex one:

```
Dim fixedDays As String
fixedDays = "'20180101:V','20180102:V','20180106:W','20180107:W','20180113:W','20180114:W','20180120:W','20180121:W','20180124:V','20180127:W','20180128:W','20180203:W'"

Dim str As Variant
For Each str In Split(Replace(Replace(Replace(fixedDays, "'", ""), ":W", ""), ":V", ""), ",")
    Debug.Print str
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a similar approach to the one posted by DisplayName, but only after you get your matches:

```
Dim big_string As String
Dim sREG As New RegExp
Dim result As Variant
Dim sRES As MatchCollection

big_string = "var fixedDays =['20180101:V','20180102:V','20180106:W','20180107:W','20180113:W','20180114:W','20180120:W','20180121:W','20180124:V','20180127:W','20180128:W','20180203:W'];"

With sREG
 .Global = True
 .Pattern = "var fixedDays\s*=\s*\[((?:'\d{8}:[VW]',?)+)];"
 .IgnoreCase = True
End With

Set sRES = sREG.Execute(big_string)
If sRES.Count > 0 Then
  result = Split(Replace(Replace(Replace(sRES(0).SubMatches(0), "'", ""), ":V", ""), ":W", ""), ",")
End If
```

Output:

[image]

You may actually collect the matches into a Collection.

The regex, `var fixedDays\s*=\s*\[((?:'\d{8}:[VW]',?)+)];`, will match `var fixedDays`, a `=` enlosed with 0+ whitespaces, then `[`, and then `((?:'\d{8}:[VW]',?)+)` will capture into Group 1 the single-quoted 8 digit numbers with `:V` or `:W` prefixes followed with an optional `,`. Then, `];` will get matched.